# Upgrade feature to add new site columns in site and in content type

Tags: 2010, feature, upgrade, lifecycle

We have a SP feature that add site columns to site and same columns to site content type. Need to upgrade feature to add

new site columns in site and in content types as well.

Followed exact steps mentioned in blog to update XML for feature upgrade -

[How to add a field to a contenttype with feature upgrade, for NEW and existing sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42744/how-to-add-a-field-to-a-contenttype-with-feature-upgrade-for-new-)

and-existing-s

But new site columns are not coming in site and adding in content type.

Need your help regarding

1. Actual deployment steps to follow to upgrade feature so that new site columns start showing up.
2. There are libraries which are created using existing content type, we want new columns in content types to push down

in existing libraries. ( used PUSHDOWN = TRUE in feature XML)

Thanks in advance

Comment: As per my understanding we need to run "upgrade" powershell command or upgrade feature through UI using “Manage Feature Upgrades" option. I think both of these options will only start working if Feature upgrade toolkit from http://spfeatureupgrade.codeplex.com/ is installed on SP server.

Any idea of any other option to upgrade a feature without installing  this toolkit.
Regards,

Ankush